# Conversion directly in LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I work with the Entity Framework and I have a LINQ query like this:

```
var foo = from ee in context.Table select new {id = ee.id, price = ee.price}.ToList();
```

where price is decimal (smallmoney in SqlServer).
Now I bind it to a datagridview by
    mydgv.DataSource = foo;
But first, I would like to convert all the decimals to strings in order to remove zeros from the value (ex. now it is 26.0000 and I want it to be 26.00). How can I do that?
Something like:

```
bla.ForEach( x => x.price.ToString().Substring(0,3))
```

won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = foo.Select(x => new { id = x.id, price = x.price.ToString("N2") } );
```

But you can probably set a format-string on the column in the datagridview to "N2" and bind directly to your original datasource. Something like:

```
dgv.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: That won't even compile, `ForEach()` expects an `Action<T>`, i.e. a function that doesn't return a value.

Comment: That's a good answer and I will use formatting on the dgv's column. However, the method with x.price.ToString() does not work (I tried it) as there comes: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the 'ToString' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @user1086396 yep, that needs to be done on the list before you bind it to the grid, not on the actual DB query. But go with the format string on the column and you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if EF supports it, but try

```
new { ee.id, price = ee.price.ToString("f2") }
```